# MVP Pattern Android для больших приложений

Tags: java, android, view, mvp

Пробую постигать MVP Pattern для Android приложений. Сама суть, вроде, ясна, но для совсем небольших приложений, которые обычно и бывают в примерах. При создании большого приложения возник ряд вопросов, а именно:

1. Например, в приложении 10 activity. Следует ли создавать 10 presenter и model? Видел информацию, что 1 view = 1 presenter.
2. Следует ли создавать presenter, если в конкретной активити к нему обращаются лишь однажды и он вызывает одноименный метод у view, где и реализован intent для перехода к следующей activity? Или это можно делать напрямую из view?
3. Как правильно реализовать "отписку" presentera от view, дабы избежать утечек памяти?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1)Например, в приложении 10 activity. Следует ли создавать 10
>   presenter и model? Видел информацию, что 1 view = 1 presenter.

Да, лучше придерживаться паттерна 1 презентер - 1 вью. Исключение, если какая то логика часто переиспользуется. Но если она переиспользуется, то высокий шанс, что и вьюха тоже, а значит можно выделить эту логику в отдельную связку вью-презентер.

> 2)Следует ли создавать presenter, если в конкретной активити к нему
>   обращаются лишь однажды и он вызывает одноименный метод у view, где и
>   реализован intent для перехода к следующей activity?

Тут важно отличать события в презентере:

1 тип - Если событие такое, что данные должны сохраняться при пересоздании вью, то это нужно делать через презентер, чтобы не ходить за данными два раза. Например, вы нажали на кнопку, чтобы скачать список новостей. Он скачался, вы закешировали его в презентере(как вариант, сохранили в глобальную переменную в презентере) и отобразили. Пользователь повернул экран, данные из кеша подгрузились, вместо того, чтобы делать заново запрос.

2 тип - События навигации, отображение тоста и похожее - это события, которые должны произойти один раз. Вы не хотите, чтобы когда повернулся экран, появился тост с ошибкой еще раз.

**Теперь ответ.**

Если это событие первого типа, то очевидно что это надо делать через презентер. Это как раз один из кейсов для которого мы его и создаем. Если это событие второго типа, то решаете вы или договоренности в вашей команде. Главное, чтобы подход был **консистентный**. Если на одном экране для вашего кейса с интентом вы сделали презентер, а на другом экране не сделали, то это запутывает при чтении кода и лучше придерживаться одного стиля.

> 3)Как правильно реализовать "отписку" presentera от view, дабы
>   избежать утечек памяти?

В onDestroy в Activity вызываете метод презентера, в котором зануляете ссылку на вью.

В onDestroyView в Fragment делаете тоже самое, если пользуетесь фрагментами

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что 10 моделей создавать не надо, если работа из всех view будет происходить с одной БД? Просто реализовать методы всех presenter в единственной model. Хотя, скорее всего, даже если источник не один, можно использовать одну model, верно? По остальным вопросам всё понял, благодарю.

Comment: да не надо, создавайте по необходимости, но одна модель это тоже плохо, она быстро станет огромной. Лучше создавать модели по логическим блокам(фичам). Например, за работу с новостями отвечает одна модель, за работу с профилем пользователя другая.  Почитайте про паттерн Repository в андроиде.

Comment: @Valgaal да, отличный совет, нет необходимости, как в прочем и в MVP, сделайте все в одном классе (и будет помойка)